# How to retrieve attributes with XPath and Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<RECORD>
<TYPE ID="check_ping">
<HOSTS>
<HOST H="192.168.0.1" W="50,1%" C="100,1%" />
<HOST H="192.168.0.2" W="50,1%" C="70,1%" />
</HOSTS>
</TYPE>
<TYPE ID="check_ssh">
<HOSTS>
<HOST H="192.168.0.3" P="21"/>
<HOST H="192.168.0.4" P="21"/>
<HOST H="192.168.0.4" P="21"/>
</HOSTS>
</TYPE>
....
</RECORD>
```

I have also a Perl script that is supposed to read that XML, I am using *XML::XPath module*.

```
use XML::XPath;
#.....
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'test.xml');
#RETRIEVE ALL HOSTS WITH CHECK_SSH
my $querysshh = '/RECORD/TYPE[@ID="check_ssh"]/HOSTS/HOST';
$nodeset = $xp->find($querysshh);
foreach $mynode ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
#HOW DO I RETRIEVE ATTRIBUTES NOW?
}
#.....
```

How can I retrieve the attributes of those nodes? For example if I want to read *H* and *P* what do I need to do? I looked at the module documentation but I couldnt find any useful method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try whether `$myNode->getAttribute("H")` works.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin has pointed out, the `getAttribute` method should work fine. You can find other available methods in [XML::XPath::Node::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aXPath%3a%3aNode%3a%3aElement) documentation.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, there is no reference to that documentation in XML::Path so I didnt know where to look. Many thanks!

Comment: @raz3r - there is a link to it from [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::XPath#Node_Object_Model) documentation (see Node Object Model section).